# Replacing the values of `edgelist` with those of a `labels` dictionary

Tags: list, loops, dictionary, list-comprehension, networkx

I am new to both Python and NetworkX. I have a square, regular graph `G` with `NxN` nodes (a *lattice*). Such nodes are labelled by means of a `dict` (see code below). Now I want the `edgelist` to return the **start** and **endpoint** of each edge not by referring to the node coordinates but to the label the node has been given.

Example:

```
N = 3
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)
labels = dict( ((i, j), i + (N-1-j) * N ) for i, j in G.nodes() )
#This gives nodes an attribute ID that is identical to their labels
for (i,j) in labels:
    G.node[(i,j)] ['ID']= labels[(i,j)]
edgelist=G.edges() #This gives the list of all edges in the format (Start XY, End XY)
```

If I run it with `N=3` I get:

```
In [14]: labels
Out[14]: {(0, 0): 6, (0, 1): 3, (0, 2): 0, (1, 0): 7, (1, 1): 4, (1, 2): 1, (2, 0): 8, (2, 1): 5, (2, 2): 2}
```

This scheme labels the upper left node as `0`, with node `(N-1)th` being placed in the lower right corner. And this is what I want. Now the problem with `edgelist`:

```
In [15]: edgelist
Out [15]: [((0, 1), (0, 0)), ((0, 1), (1, 1)), ((0, 1), (0, 2)), ((1, 2), (1, 1)), ((1, 2), (0, 2)), ((1, 2), (2, 2)), ((0, 0), (1, 0)), ((2, 1), (2, 0)), ((2, 1), (1, 1)), ((2, 1), (2, 2)), ((1, 1), (1, 0)), ((2, 0), (1, 0))]
```

I tried to solve the problem with these lines (inspiration from here: [Replace items in a list using a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273691/replace-items-in-a-list-using-a-dictionary)):

```
allKeys = {}
for subdict in (labels):
    allKeys.update(subdict)

new_edgelist = [allKeys[edge] for edge in edgelist]
```

but I get this wonderful thing which enlightens my monday:

```
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

**To sum up**, I want to be able to replace the elements of the `edgelist` list with the values of the `labels` dictionary so that, say, the edge from `((2,0),(1,0))` (which correspond to nodes *8* and *7*) is returned `(8,7)`. **Endless thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is simply `nx.relabel_nodes(G,labels,False)` here is the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/relabel.html)

> Here is the output when I printed the nodes of G before and after calling the relabel nodes function.

```
# Before relabel_nodes
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0), (1, 1)]
# After relabel_nodes
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

> After doing this, the edge labels automatically becomes what you expect.

```
# Edges before relabelling nodes
[((0, 1), (0, 0)), ((0, 1), (1, 1)), ((1, 0), (0, 0)), ((1, 0), (1, 1))]
# Edges after relabelling nodes
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Also, I have replied to this question in the chat that you created but it seems you were not notified.

Comment: Thank you very much. I indeed had a number of problems with the chat so yes, I was not notified. I apologize for not having read about this before. :)

Comment: Btw, the documentation isn't very helpful and descriptive. If `G` is my graph and the `labels` are those that have been set in another question, how can I be sure that no jumps/flaws/mistakes are introduced? I guess it is because of the way `labels` is defined, correct?

Comment: I am not quite sure I understood your question. But yes the labels definition is essential for flawless results

Comment: If I place the `relabel` line before drawing the graph, Python throws an error: `NetworkXError: Node 0 has no position.`. Why?

Comment: Yes because the pos dictionary you are sending to the networkx draw function maps nodes with keys in format (i,j) and you have changed the labels so the function can not find a position for the node labeled 0. Thus, you have to adapt the pos dictionary to map from n:(i,j)

Comment: So I think I have a bigger problem now. Sorry for being so demanding but relabeling the nodes causes additional problems. Anyhow, I must relabel them... do you know how to turn this into a chat? Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually the chat link you created sends me to the chat room, is it not working for you ? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92866/discussion-between-francesco-castellani-and-abdallah-sobehy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93374/discussion-between-abdallah-sobehy-and-francesco-castellani).

Comment: I am not sure of you are receiving a notification for the chat but you have to check the link, I answered there. @FrancescoCastellani